# Simple random walk with drift

Tags: probability, random-variables, random-walk

Let $(X_i)_{i\in \mathbb{N}}$ a sequence of i.i.d. random variables, such that

$$\mathbb{P}(X_i=1)=p=1-\mathbb{P}(X_i=-1)$$

Suppose that $p\geq\frac{3}{4}$ and consider $S_n=\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i$.
I want to show that $\mathbb{P}(S_n<\frac{1}{2}n)$ decays exponentially in $n$. Any suggestion of concentration's inequalities that can help me?

Comment: The currently stated result is false.  OP wrote "Suppose that $p\geq \frac{3}{4}$... I want to show that $P(S_n \lt \frac{1}{2}n)$ decays exponentially in ."  Now suppose we focus on odd $n$ and $p=\frac{3}{4}$.  then $E[S_n] = \mu_n = \frac{1}{2}n$ and $P(S_n = \mu_n) = 0$.  If the statement is true then $ \epsilon \cdot (\mu - \frac{1}{2}) + (1-\epsilon)\cdot (\mu+\frac{1}{2}) = \mu +\frac{1}{2} (1-2\epsilon)\lt  E[S_n]=\mu_n $  for arbitrarily small $\epsilon\gt 0$ for large enough n, not to mention the CLT breaks, and so do many other results.

Comment: Sorry, where exactly did you use my statement?

Comment: to my knowledge concentration inequalities never come up in a basic intro to probability, so I'm trying to get *you* to fill in the details as to why your statement can never be true when $p=\frac{3}{4}$ -- i.e. apply total expectation and lower bound $E[S_n]$ using $\mathbb{P}(S_n<\frac{1}{2}n)\lt \epsilon$ for any epsilon $\gt 0$ for large enough $n$ (which is implied by exponential/geometric decay in $\mathbb{P}(S_n<\frac{1}{2}n)$ which your post claimed occurs).  This results in a contradiction.  What book is this from?  Is there an errata sheet?

Comment: It is not an exercise, it is something I imagined, but from what I saw, it is wrong. In fact, I need this probability goes to zero. The speed of convergence is not important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $B_n:=(S_n+n)/2$ s.t. $B_n\sim \text{Bin}(n,p)$. Using the bound derived in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1207.3838.pdf), one gets

\begin{align}
\mathsf{P}(S_n<n/2)&=\mathsf{P}(B_n\le \lceil3n/4-1\rceil) \\
&\le \Phi\!\left(\operatorname{sgn}(a_n-np)\sqrt{2n H(p,a_n/n)}\right),
\end{align}
where $a_n:=\lceil 3n/4-1\rceil+1$ and $H(p, c):=c\ln(c/p)+(1−c)\ln((1 − c)/(1 − p))$. For $p>3/4$, the sign of $(a_n-np)$ becomes negative for all $n$ large enough so that, eventually,
$$
\mathsf{P}(S_n<n/2)\le 1-\Phi\!\left(\sqrt{2n H(p,a_n/n)}\right)\le \frac{\phi(\sqrt{2n H(p,a_n/n))}}{\sqrt{2n H(p,a_n/n)}}.
$$